# populate drop down box with numbers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple. I am trying to populate a drop down box with the numbers 1-5.  When ever I run the page, my drop down box is blank.

Any help? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
    var maxAllowed = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    for (var i = 0; i < maxAllowed.length; i++) {
        $("#attemptsDDL").append($("option />").val(i).html(i));
    }
```

Comment: You're just missing `<` in `<option />`?

Comment: You missed a `<`.  `$("#attemptsDDL").append($("<option />").val(i).html(i));`

Comment: Another pair of eyes always helps! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fixed:

```
var maxAllowed = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    for (var i = 0; i < maxAllowed.length; i++) {
        $("#attemptsDDL").append($("<option />").val(i).html(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.

```
$("option />")
```

should be

```
$("<option />")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `option />` to `<option />` first of all.